# download excel file with response.contenttype

Tags: excel, asp-classic

can a download of excel file with response. contenttype be proccessed without the saveas window so the file will be opened automaticly?

Comment: Depends on the browser - if the proper plugin is installed, the file will be loaded inside the browser unless special header is added, which I assume you don't add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. I think the only way this will work is if each and every client had an appropriate plug-in (like Adobe has for Acrobat), so that the browser would know what to do with the content.

With out the plug-in, the best you can do is have the Open/Save As/Cancel dialog open up, or, specify that via the content-disposition that this is an attachment and always have the Save As dialog open up, optionally with a predefined file name.

Comment: Specifically, this is a client-side setting, and cannot be done by the server alone (though you can achieve the opposite, with `content-disposition: attachment`.